# How Do I Blur a Scene in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

How would I add a gaussian blur to all nodes (there's no fixed number of nodes) in an SKScene in SpriteKit?  A label will be added on top of the scene later, this will be my pause menu.
Almost anything would help!

Something like this is what I'm going for:
[image: Gaussian pause menu]

Comment: You might find this link useful: [http://eppz.eu/blog/create-ios-7-blur-effect/](http://eppz.eu/blog/create-ios-7-blur-effect/)

Comment: No, I don't want to have to import anything, and I'd like it to be all SKScene, I can't use anything from UIView

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `SKEffectNode`. It applies a CoreImage filter to itself (and thus all subnodes). Just make it the root view of your scene, give it one of CoreImage's blur filters, and you're set.

For example, I set up an `SKScene` with an `SKEffectNode` as it's first child node and a property, `root` that holds a weak reference to it:

```
-(void)createLayers{
  SKEffectNode *node = [SKEffectNode node];
  [node setShouldEnableEffects:NO];
  CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues:@"inputRadius", @1.0f, nil];
  [node setFilter:blur];
  [self setRoot:node];
}
```

And here's the method I use to (animate!) the blur of my scene:

```
-(void)blurWithCompletion:(void (^)())handler{
  CGFloat duration = 0.5f;
  [[self root] setShouldRasterize:YES];
  [[self root] setShouldEnableEffects:YES];
  [[self root] runAction:[SKAction customActionWithDuration:duration actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime){
    NSNumber *radius = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(elapsedTime/duration) * 10.0];
    [[(SKEffectNode *)node filter] setValue:radius forKey:@"inputRadius"];
  }] completion:handler];
}
```

Note that, like you, I'm using this as a pause screen, so I rasterize the scene. If you want your scene to animate while blurred, you should probably `setShouldResterize:` to `NO`.

And if you're not interested in animating the transition to the blur, you could always just set the filter to an initial radius of `10.0f` or so and do a simple `setShouldEnableEffects:YES` when you want to switch it on.

See also: [SKEffectNode class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEffectNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html)

***UPDATE:***
See Markus's comment below. He points out that `SKScene` is, in fact, a subclass of `SKEffectNode`, so you really ought to be able to call all of this on the scene itself rather than arbitrarily inserting an effect node in your node tree.

Comment: How did you add the node as child?
    [self addChild:node]; // it drops an error => (lldb)
Have the example typed to ViewController?

Comment: I really don't understand where is the mistake.
Here is my code, http://postimg.org/image/bg8qb70rp/
It doesn't show any error, but it doesn't show any action too.

Comment: But isn't SKScene also an SKEffectNode? Couldn't you add the filter directly to the SKScene?

Comment: @MarkusRautopuro Oh my goodness, you're right! I haven't tried it yet, but I can't think of any reason applying it directly to the `SKScene` wouldn't work.

Comment: If you apply the effect to the whole scene, my bet is that the "PAUSED" label and any button to resume the game will be blurred as well. That is why I have an `SKEffectNode` be the "canvas" of all my game content, and that one is a child of the scene.

Comment: Also, this should be the accepted answer. It uses functionality already available in SpriteKit (no need for third party code, UIKit, CoreImage, etc).

Comment: Note that `shouldRasterize = YES` prevents redrawing only if the children of the effect node don't need redrawing. For your pause screen, you probably want to `pause` those nodes (or a common parent thereof) before applying the blur so that you're not trying to do fullscreen blur at 60fps and melt your GPU.

Answer (score 12):

To add to this by using @Bendegúz's answer and code from http://www.bytearray.org/?p=5360

I was able to get this to work in my current game project that's being done in IOS 8 Swift.  Done a bit differently by returning an SKSpriteNode instead of a UIImage.  Also note that my unwrapped currentScene.view! call is to a weak GameScene reference but should work with self.view.frame based on where you are calling these methods.  My pause screen is called in a separate HUD class hence why this is the case.

I would imagine this could be done more elegantly, maybe more like @jemmons's answer.  Just wanted to possibly help out anyone else trying to do this in SpriteKit projects written in all or some Swift code.

```
func getBluredScreenshot() -> SKSpriteNode{

    create the graphics context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: currentScene.view!.frame.size.width, height: currentScene.view!.frame.size.height), true, 1)

    currentScene.view!.drawViewHierarchyInRect(currentScene.view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // retrieve graphics context
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // query image from it
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // create Core Image context
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    // create a CIImage, think of a CIImage as image data for processing, nothing is displayed or can be displayed at this point
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: image)
    // pick the filter we want
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    // pass our image as input
    filter.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    //edit the amount of blur
    filter.setValue(3, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    //retrieve the processed image
    let filteredImageData = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
    // return a Quartz image from the Core Image context
    let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, fromRect: filteredImageData.extent())
    // final UIImage
    let filteredImage = UIImage(CGImage: filteredImageRef)

    // create a texture, pass the UIImage
    let texture = SKTexture(image: filteredImage!)
    // wrap it inside a sprite node
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)

    // make image the position in the center
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(currentScene.frame), CGRectGetMidY(currentScene.frame))

    var scale:CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

    sprite.size.width  *= scale

    sprite.size.height *= scale

    return sprite


}


func loadPauseBGScreen(){

    let duration = 1.0

    let pauseBG:SKSpriteNode = self.getBluredScreenshot()

    //pauseBG.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    pauseBG.alpha = 0
    pauseBG.zPosition = self.zPosition + 1
    pauseBG.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1, duration: duration))

    self.addChild(pauseBG)

}
```

Comment: Chuck, the tag says objective-c.

Answer (score 10):

This is my solution for the pause screen.
It will take a screenshot, blur it and after that show it with animation.
I think you should do it if you don't wanna waste to much fps.

```
-(void)pause {
    SKSpriteNode *pauseBG = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:[self getBluredScreenshot]]];
    pauseBG.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    pauseBG.alpha = 0;
    pauseBG.zPosition = 2;
    [pauseBG runAction:[SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1 duration:duration / 2]];
    [self addChild:pauseBG];
}
```

And this is the helper method:

```
- (UIImage *)getBluredScreenshot {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 1);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.frame afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *ss = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setDefaults];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:[CIImage imageWithCGImage:[ss CGImage]] forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:@10 forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey];

    CIImage *outputImage = [gaussianBlurFilter outputImage];
    CIContext *context   = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGRect rect          = [outputImage extent];
    rect.origin.x        += (rect.size.width  - ss.size.width ) / 2;
    rect.origin.y        += (rect.size.height - ss.size.height) / 2;
    rect.size            = ss.size;
    CGImageRef cgimg     = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:rect];
    UIImage *image       = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return image;
}
```

Comment: A little too late for the project but I'll keep it for future reference :)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4:**

add this to your gameScene if you want to blur everything in the scene:

```
let  blur = CIFilter(name:"CIGaussianBlur",withInputParameters: ["inputRadius": 10.0])
        self.filter = blur
        self.shouldRasterize = true
        self.shouldEnableEffects = false
```

change self.shouldEnableEffects = true when you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3 Update:** This is @Chuck Gaffney's answer updated for Swift 3. I know this question is tagged objective-c, but this page ranked 2nd in Google for "swift spritekit blur". I changed  *currentScene* to *self*.

```
    func getBluredScreenshot() -> SKSpriteNode{

    //create the graphics context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: self.view!.frame.size.width, height: self.view!.frame.size.height), true, 1)

    self.view!.drawHierarchy(in: self.view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // retrieve graphics context
    _ = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // query image from it
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // create Core Image context
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    // create a CIImage, think of a CIImage as image data for processing, nothing is displayed or can be displayed at this point
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: image!)
    // pick the filter we want
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    // pass our image as input
    filter?.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

    //edit the amount of blur
    filter?.setValue(3, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

    //retrieve the processed image
    let filteredImageData = filter?.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    // return a Quartz image from the Core Image context
    let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
    // final UIImage
    let filteredImage = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)

    // create a texture, pass the UIImage
    let texture = SKTexture(image: filteredImage)
    // wrap it inside a sprite node
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture:texture)

    // make image the position in the center
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    let scale:CGFloat = UIScreen.main.scale

    sprite.size.width  *= scale

    sprite.size.height *= scale

    return sprite


}

func loadPauseBGScreen(){

    let duration = 1.0

    let pauseBG:SKSpriteNode = self.getBluredScreenshot()

    pauseBG.alpha = 0
    pauseBG.zPosition = self.zPosition + 1
    pauseBG.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1, duration: duration))

    self.addChild(pauseBG)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another example of getting this done in swift 2 without the layers:

```
func blurWithCompletion() {
let duration: CGFloat = 0.5
let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius" : NSNumber(double:1.0)])!
scene!.filter = filter
scene!.shouldRasterize = true
scene!.shouldEnableEffects = true
scene!.runAction(SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.5, actionBlock: { (node: SKNode, elapsedTime: CGFloat) in
    let radius = (elapsedTime/duration)*10.0
    (node as? SKEffectNode)!.filter!.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")

}))
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this same thing now, in May 2020 (Xcode 11 and iOS 13.x), but wasn't unable to 'animate' the blur radius. In my case, I start with the scene fully blurred, and then 'unblur' it gradually (set `inputRadius` to 0).

**Somehow, the new input radius value set in the custom action block wasn't reflected in the rendered scene.** My code was as follows:

```
    private func unblur() {
        run(SKAction.customAction(withDuration: unblurDuration, actionBlock: { [weak self] (_, elapsed) in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            let ratio = (TimeInterval(elapsed) / this.unblurDuration)
            let radius = this.maxBlurRadius * (1 - ratio) // goes to 0 as ratio goes to 1
            this.filter?.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        }))
    }
```

I even tried updating the value manually using `SKScene.update(_:)` and some variables for time book-keeping, but the same result.

It occurred to me that perhaps I could force the refresh if I "re-assingned" the blur filter to the `.filter` property of my SKScene (see comments in ALL CAPS near the end of the code), to the same effect, and it worked.

The full code:

```
class MyScene: SKScene {

    private let maxBlurRadius: Double = 50
    private let unblurDuration: TimeInterval = 5

    init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)

        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        filter?.setValue(maxBlurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        self.filter = filter
        self.shouldEnableEffects = true
        self.shouldRasterize = false

        // (...rest of the child nodes, etc...)

    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to: view)
        self.unblur()
    }

    private func unblur() {
        run(SKAction.customAction(withDuration: unblurDuration, actionBlock: { [weak self] (_, elapsed) in
            guard let this = self else { return }
            let ratio = (TimeInterval(elapsed) / this.unblurDuration)
            let radius = this.maxBlurRadius * (1 - ratio) // goes to 0 as ratio goes to 1

            // OBTAIN THE FILTER
            let filter = this.filter

            // MODIFY ATTRIBUTE 
            filter?.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

            // RE=ASSIGN TO SCENE
            this.filter = filter
        }))
    }
}
```

**I hope this helps someone!**