# Apply a UIBlurEffect over a SpriteKit scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, ios8

I have a standard SpriteKit hierarchy: my UIViewController contains a SKView, which is presenting my SKScene. I want to be able to blur everything out when pausing my scene, so I'm adding a UIVisualEffectView with a UIBlurEffect as a subview of my SKView. This applies the lightness/darkness part of the UIBlurEffect (so I know I'm setting the frame properly), but fails to actually blur any of the nodes in my scene. iOS 8 bug, or developer error?

Comment: use the scene's effectNode

Comment: This is the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490818/how-do-i-blur-a-scene-in-spritekit

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. When you initialize your scene, in your GameViewVontroller, pass your skView along. Then in your GameScene.swift you can do it as follows:

```
        var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)) as UIVisualEffectView

    visualEffectView.frame = myView.bounds

    myView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```