# How to blur a scene in Swift 2

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm trying to blur a scene when I pause a game and I'm following an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22490818/how-do-i-blur-a-scene-in-spritekit) but I'm unable to work it out in Swift 2.0.

A lot of tutorials say to just take a screenshot and then present that screenshot as blurred but I don't think that's a good idea, I'd like to blur the view without a screenshot.

here is my attempt:

```
func createlayers() {
    let node = SKEffectNode()
    node.shouldEnableEffects = false
    let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius" : NSNumber(double:1.0)])!
    node.filter = filter
}

func blurWithCompletion() {
    let duration: CGFloat = 0.5
    scene!.shouldRasterize = true
    scene!.shouldEnableEffects = true
    scene!.runAction(SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.5, actionBlock: { (node: SKNode, elapsedTime: CGFloat) in
        let radius = (elapsedTime/duration)*10.0
        (node as? SKEffectNode)!.filter!.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")

    }))
}

func pauseGame()
{
    self.blurWithCompletion()
    self.view!.paused = true 

}
```

I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Try this let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius" : NSNumber(double:1.0)])!

Comment: Hey Arun, thanks for pointing this, I actually had this already in the code just forgot to add it, I made a couple changes to reflect that, could you please look at this over again? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create layers method is not required. 
Use this updated blurWithCompletion method:

```
    func blurWithCompletion() {
    let duration: CGFloat = 0.5
    let filter: CIFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius" : NSNumber(double:1.0)])!
    scene!.filter = filter
    scene!.shouldRasterize = true
    scene!.shouldEnableEffects = true
    scene!.runAction(SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.5, actionBlock: { (node: SKNode, elapsedTime: CGFloat) in
        let radius = (elapsedTime/duration)*10.0
        (node as? SKEffectNode)!.filter!.setValue(radius, forKey: "inputRadius")

    }))
}
```